# how to stop refreshing page in php

Tags: php, reload

```
if(isset($_POST["subSubmit"])){
 if($_POST["subSubmit"]=="Send") {
  $sentto    = $_POST['txtSentto'];
  $sentcc    = $_POST['txtcc'];
 $sel="insert into newmessage set sendto='".$sentto."', 
                  sentcc='".$sentcc."'";
 $selqur=mysql_query($sel) or die("Error (" . mysql_errno() .")" . mysql_error());
 }
}
```

i am php beginner i dont know how to stop the reload page.For the above program not reload without submit button once submit button clicked data stored in database and then click refreshing the page the data automatically send to database.Plz give any ideas             thank you

Comment: Just a style note, instead of having two nested if statements you can use just one: if(isset($_POST["subSubmit"] && $_POST["subSubmit"]=="Send").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the [POST / Redirect / GET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern.

Also, [sanitize your outside variables (`$_POST`) being used in your SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).